# How to set side padding to GridView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, gridview, android-gridview

I'm `Android` app developer. My problem about `GirdView` UI.
I want to set inside `padding` to `GridView`. Follow my picture.

[image]

I want to **set scrollbar to align right of device, like picture.** So means, I want to **set only side padding of `GridView`**. I wonder how can set ***`A`*** size?

My GridView source :

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/wizard_sports_gridView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_600px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_60px"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:columnWidth="@dimen/_110px" />
```

How can I do for set side padding of `GridView`?

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to put the GridView inside a LinearLayout and add side padding to the LinearLayout, like this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
        android:paddingLeft=" <A> dp"
        android:paddingRight=" <A> dp">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/wizard_sports_gridView"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_600px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_60px"
            android:numColumns="4"
            android:columnWidth="@dimen/_110px" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give padding to `GridView` as you normally give by using

```
android:paddingLeft="28dp"
android:paddingRight="28dp"
```

now you want the `ScrollBar` to the right side for that you will need to add following property to `GridView` and set it to `false`

```
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

so now your `GridView` in xml will be

```
<GridView
  android:id="@+id/wizard_sports_gridView"
  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
  android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
  android:layout_width="@dimen/_600px"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_60px"
  android:numColumns="4"
  android:paddingLeft="28dp"  <!-- Change with your padding values -->
  android:paddingRight="28dp"
  android:clipToPadding="false"
  android:columnWidth="@dimen/_110px" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use negative  padding

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/wizard_sports_gridView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
        android:layout_width="600dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:columnWidth="110sp" 
        android:padding="-50dp"/>
```